# Magento 1.8 admin username and password correct but not login & menu click redirect to other page

Tags: magento-1.8, admin

Am new in Magento, I'm using Magento 1.8 and local server `Xampp`. I was migrating my Magento store `Live Server` to `localhost`. After migrating some error are defining.

1. When i try to login admin enterd this link `http//127.0.01/magento/admin` or click `front-end` store menu it automatically move to `http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/`
2. admin panel **username** and **password** correct but not redirect to **dashboard**.

In databse am changed `core_config_data` that are following

- `web/unsecure/base_url` as `http://127.0.0.1/magento/`
- `web/secure/base_url` as `http://127.0.0.1/magento/`

And clear all cache files in `var/cache` folder and session files `var/session` folder. Then `local.xml` changed dbname, username, password.

How can i solve this errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ramesh/mirror-white/
    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

To

`RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`

Comment: You mean replace this code in .htaccess file `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Comment: where is .htaccess file location...?

Comment: In your root directory after `var` folder

Comment: It's working fine. But i can't login admin same error. but 1st one cleared thank you